# Obter o pai passando o código do filho utilizando Hierarchical Data (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como faço para obter `EmployeeID`  do pai passando o `EmployeeID` do filho da tabela abaixo utilizando a variável do tipo `hierarchyid` no SQL Server?

```
  CREATE TABLE Employee
    (
       Node hierarchyid PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
       EmployeeID int UNIQUE NOT NULL,
       EmpName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
       Title varchar(20) NULL
    ) ;
    GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o metodo [GetAncestor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677202.aspx), ele retorna o hierarchyid referente a posição inserida.

No seu caso, ele retornará a primeira posição. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
    SELECT 
         EmployeeID 
    FROM 
         Employee
    WHERE 
        [Node] IN (
                   SELECT
                       [Node].GetAncestor(1).ToString()
                   FROM
                       Employee
                   WHERE 
                       EmployeeID=4
                   )
```

Você também pode visualizar através do [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02e25/5)

Comment: Muito obrigado, muito simples, e obrigado por mostra o SQLFiddle, não conhecia essa ferramenta.